# xslt 2.0 multiple grouping

Tags: xslt, grouping, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

My Question: How can I apply double (or multiple) grouping?

Here is the source XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<root>
    <row>
        <Type>1</Type>
        <WeaNr>100519</WeaNr>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Type>2</Type>
        <WeaNr>100519</WeaNr>
        <ETADC_SKU>2007925</ETADC_SKU>
        <CrossDock>N</CrossDock>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Type>2</Type>
        <WeaNr>100519</WeaNr>
        <ETADC_SKU>12007925</ETADC_SKU>
        <CrossDock>N</CrossDock>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Type>2</Type>
        <WeaNr>100519</WeaNr>
        <ETADC_SKU>200792ww5</ETADC_SKU>
        <CrossDock>Y</CrossDock>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Type>1</Type>
        <WeaNr>100520</WeaNr>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Type>2</Type>
        <WeaNr>100520</WeaNr>
        <ETADC_SKU>2007925444</ETADC_SKU>
        <CrossDock>N</CrossDock>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Type>2</Type>
        <WeaNr>100520</WeaNr>
        <ETADC_SKU>2007925333</ETADC_SKU>
        <CrossDock>Y</CrossDock>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Type>2</Type>
        <WeaNr>100520</WeaNr>
        <ETADC_SKU>204445333</ETADC_SKU>
        <CrossDock>Y</CrossDock>
    </row>
</root>
```

I want use grouping by `WeaNr` and `CrossDock`

Expected results in this case are 4 groups:

```
1. WeaNr=100519 and CrossDock=N
2. WeaNr=100519 and CrossDock=Y
3. WeaNr=100520 and CrossDock=N
4. WeaNr=100520 and CrossDock=Y
```

Grouping just by one field, like WeaNr is easy:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="row" group-by="WeaNr">
```

So how can I apply double (or multiple) grouping?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You would `group-by` some string that is a combination of the two, for example

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="row" group-by="concat(WeaNr, '|', CrossDock)">
```

or alternatively use two nested levels of `for-each-group`

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="row" group-by="WeaNr">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="CrossDock">
```

The difference between these two approaches is apparent if you use the `position()` function in the body of the `for-each-group` - in the `concat` case you'll get position values from 1 to 4, in the nested case you'll get 1, 2, 1, 2 (because the `position()` is determined by the *nearest* enclosing `for-each-group`).  Similarly, `last()` will be 4 in the `concat` case and 2 in the nested case.

Comment: Also, of course, current-grouping-key() will be different in the two cases.